# Documenting null values with Spring REST Docs

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc, spring-restdocs

Let's say we have the following API:

```java
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    @GetMapping("/api/person")
    public List<Person> findPeople() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Person("Doe", "Foo", "John"), new Person("Doe", null, "Jane"));
    }
}
```

Where the model class looks like this:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private String firstName;
}
```

As you can see in the controller, the `middleName` property of the second object in the list is `null`. I'm now trying to use Spring REST Docs to document the properties of the API, so I wrote the following test:

```java
@Test
public void findAllReturnsPeople() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/person").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].firstName", is("John")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].middleName", is("Foo")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].lastName", is("Doe")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[1].firstName", is("Jane")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[1].middleName", nullValue()))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[1].lastName", is("Doe")))
        .andDo(document("person-get", responseFields(
            fieldWithPath("[].firstName").description("The given name of a person"),
            fieldWithPath("[].middleName").description("The optionally given middle name of a person"),
            fieldWithPath("[].lastName").description("The last- or family name of a person"))));
}
```

By using the `responseFields()` and `fieldWithPath()` properties, I'm trying to give a description to each field. However, this approach fails for the middle name, throwing the following exception:

```java
org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: Fields with the following paths were not found in the payload: [[].middleName]

    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.validateFieldDocumentation(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:257)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.createModel(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:167)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:83)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.generate.RestDocumentationGenerator.handle(RestDocumentationGenerator.java:206)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationResultHandler.handle(RestDocumentationResultHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andDo(MockMvc.java:183)
    at be.g00glen00b.apps.demoempty.DemoEmptyApplicationTests.findAllReturnsPeople(DemoEmptyApplicationTests.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

However, when I change the code and change the middle name of the second `Person` object to `"Bar"`, the error disappears, and the snippet is correctly generated.

Additionally, when I remove the `fieldWithPath("[].middleName")` code, and I run the test, I get the following exception:

```java
org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: The following parts of the payload were not documented:
[ {
  "middleName" : "Foo"
}, {
  "middleName" : null
} ]
```

Which makes sense, since the middle name property isn't documented in that case.

My question is how can I prevent this error and document what the `middleName` property does?

This is what I tried so far:

- Documenting only the non-null value, eg `[0].middleName` (this leads to the same exception)
- Changing the type explicitely to `JsonFieldType.STRING`or `JsonFieldType.VARIES` (this also leads to the same exception)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell REST Docs that the field is optional. You can do this by calling the `optional()` method on the `FieldDescriptor`:

```
.andDo(document("person-get", responseFields(
        fieldWithPath("[].firstName").description("The given name of a person"),
        fieldWithPath("[].middleName").description("The optionally given middle name of a person").optional(),
        fieldWithPath("[].lastName").description("The last- or family name of a person"))));
```